# How do I access claims inside an AuthorizationHandler?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2) resource for creating an AuthorizationHandler and followed along to create one. My handler checks for `given_name`, a string value, and if `given_name` has a value of `"Bob"`, authorization success.

The problem, I can't access the `given_name` claim and its value. I can see all the expected claims when I inspect `context.User` but `context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName)` always returns false.

How do I check for the presence of a claim and get its value?

Update - As a workaround, I can access all the claims by calling .ToList() on `context.User.Claims` and then using .Any() on the list. It works but I haven't seen this approach in any examples.

Comment: I see you have `IdentityServer4` tag. Are you using `ASP.NET Core Identity` for the user management?

Comment: @DavidLiang - I'm using external authentication (Google) and attempting to access claims provided by Google.

Comment: `HasClaim` should work to check if a given claim exists. You shouldn't be calling `ToList` on it since it's very inefficient. `ClaimsPrincipal` may have multiple `Identity`.. look here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Security.Claims/src/System/Security/Claims/ClaimsPrincipal.cs#L228. Are you sure the `given_name` is returned in the token?

Answer (score 0):

For Asp.NET Core 6, you can pass in the [AuthorizationHandlerContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationhandlercontext?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Here is a sample AuthorizationHandler that leverages that context for a ClaimsPrincipal.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace MyIdentityApp.Security
{
    public class CanReadAffiliatedOwnerInfoHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ManageAffiliatedOwnerInfoRequirement>
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ManageAffiliatedOwnerInfoRequirement requirement)
        {
            var authFilterContext = (HttpContext?)context.Resource;

            if (authFilterContext == null)
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            else
            {
                //access user's claims here, via context.User
                var loggedInUserAffiliatedOwners = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value == OwnerIdAttemptingToAccess);

                if (loggedInUserAffiliatedOwners != null)
                {
                    context.Succeed(requirement);
                }
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```